# A FATAL ERROR while submitting the signup form in PHP

Tags: mysqli, localhost

I'm a student and I was writing a signup script but I don't know why I'm getting this error, according to me every thing is fine and PHPStrom v2018.3.1 also not showing me any sign of error but when I submit the form I get this error.

Error:"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in D:\xampp\htdocs\electronic_store\signup.php:26 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\electronic_store\signup.php on line 26".

CODE:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['btnRegister']))
{
    $id = rand(1111,9999);
    $name = $_POST('name');
    $email = $_POST('email');
    $password = md5($_POST('password'));
    $phone = $_POST('phone');

    if(mysqli_query($con,"insert into register values('$id','$name','$password','$email','$phone','employee')"))
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Register Successfully');</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Error');</script>";
    }
```

}

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Check out [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**$_POST**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) should be with square brackets not round brackets that's why it is returning errors.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
```

Comment: $password = md5[$_POST('password')];      Still not resolved.

Comment: @MHassanAli it will be like this `$password = md5($_POST['password']);`

Comment: thanks buddy for your guidance, I just changed all round brackets with square brackets.                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        $id = 'user' .rand(1111,9999);
 $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];

Comment: thanks again for telling me about marking the answer.